# Rollback of a C# MVC application causes caching issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I perform a rollback to a previous build my clients seem to have issues where some files remain stuck in their browser caches. The sequence of events is:

- Deploy with build "B" that has the same .html file last modified at 1/2/2016
- Make a browser request for the .html file
- Deploy an **older** build "A" that has the same .html file last modified at 1/1/2016
- Make a browser request for the same .html file

At the end of the sequence of events, the clients browser will make a Request with the header If-Modified-Since:1/2/2010 which will get a response 304 Not Modified and will get the wrong file version!

Is this correct or are we looking at a red herring to another issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behavior. It makes sense that's what you are seeing. You can modify IIS to expire everything right now. See the following link.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(v=ws.10).aspx

If this is hosted in Azure, you can go to tools -> console (in the azure portal) and open a command prompt. Then run `touch <filename>`. This will update the timestamp and invalidate the cache.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response! What's the best way for me to alter this behavior such that rolling back doesn't have this issue? I think I need to remove the last-modified header from my responses so that it relies solely on Etag for sending 304 messages. Is that correct?

I have a system that will automatically rollback the build in a certain circumstance, so there can't be any manual intervention (which is todays solution)

Comment: You could solely use Etags, or you could write a powershell script that enumerates every file in the directory and runs the "touch" command when you rollback.

Comment: When I removed the Last-Modified header I noticed a browser request still sent the If-None-Match header and the server responded with a matching ETag value but with a 200 response instead of a 304! What gives?

Comment: The ETag was responding with a 200 because Akamai, the front door technology in front of my origin servers by default has ETag disabled by default